# How to change Read more option in the front page of drupal 7?

Tags: nodes

I am using drupal7. If we published a content to "promoted to front page". It will act as from the default front page view. I want to change the "Read More" option as "More". Where i can change the option? Please help me?

Thanks,
Sathish

Answer (score 3):

```
function MODULE_node_view_alter(&$build){
  if( isset($build['links']['node']['#links']['node-readmore']['title']) )
    $build['links']['node']['#links']['node-readmore']['title'] = t('More');
}
```

You can apply more checks in order to change the link title for some special scenario or for some specific content type.

Comment: Thanks for giving the function, where i can paste those function, either in views module or template file.

Comment: You need to create your own custom module. Create a directory in modules directory for your custom module. Provide two files .info and .module and put this code in .module file. Writing .info files (http://drupal.org/node/542202) .module is common PHP file.

Comment: Thanks for giving this solution, I have created the custom module as per your instruction and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can also edit the node.module file changing 'Read more<span ..... to 'More as I did below:

```
if ($view_mode == 'teaser') {
  $node_title_stripped = strip_tags($node->title);
  $links['node-readmore'] = array(
    'title' => t('More<span class="element-invisible"> about @title</span>', array(
       '@title' => $node_title_stripped
     )
   ),
```

Answer (score 0):

[String Overrides Module](https://drupal.org/project/stringoverrides) have been my best bet when not in mood to touch codes for small things like that.

Define *Read more* in **Original** and *More* in **Replacement**.

[image]